# curl -b cookies -c cookies -X POST -d @some_auth.json url --- python equivalent

Tags: python, json, curl, cookies, session-cookies

The above command line make a curl request using data from the json file passed to it with -d option and gets cookies and stores them in a cookies folder.

These cookies can be used in subsequent curl requests without explicitly specifying the credentials.

I am trying to convert the above command line to python code.
Have tried following code snippets but none of it worked.

**Code 1:**

```
import requests, sys, json

s = requests.Session()
url = 'some_url'

r = s.post(url, data={'cmd': 'login', 'loginname': 'some_login', 'password': 'some_password' } )
print(s.cookies)
```

**Code 2:**

```
from requests import Session

import requests, sys, json

reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding("utf8")

f = open("auth.json", "r")
p = json.load(f)

url = 'https://api.some.com/auth'
s = requests.Session()

service_url = 'http://api.some.com/some_service'
r= requests.get(url, auth=(p['login'], p['password']))

c = r.cookies

r = requests.get(service_url, cookies = c, verify = False)

print(c)
```

The second code is trying to authenticate and use the cookies in the second request.

Thanks in Advance for any help!!!!

Comment: `sys.setdefaultencoding("utf8")` is a nasty hack that hides all kinds of problems - https://anonbadger.wordpress.com/2015/06/16/why-sys-setdefaultencoding-will-break-code/

Answer (score 0):

The cookie parameter is a dictionary data type. Replace `c = r.cookies` with following code:

```
c = r.cookies.get_dict()
```